# Match an element of every line

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

I have a list of rules for a given input file for my function. If any of them are violated in the file given, I want my program to return an error message and quit.

- Every gene in the file should be on the same chromosome

Thus for a lines such as:

NM_001003443 chr11 + 5997152 5927598 5921052 5926098 1 5928752,5925972, 5927204,5396098,
NM_001003444 chr11 + 5925152 5926098 5925152 5926098 2 5925152,5925652, 5925404,5926098,
NM_001003489 chr11 + 5925145 5926093 5925115 5926045 4 5925151,5925762, 5987404,5908098,
etc.

Each line in the file will be variations of this line

Thus, I want to make sure every line in the file is on chr11

Yet I may be given a file with a different list of chr(and any number of numbers). Thus I want to write a function that will make sure whatever number is found on chr in the line is the same for every line.

Should I use a regular expression for this, or what should I do? This is in python by the way.

Such as: chr\d+ ?
I am unsure how to make sure that whatever is matched is the same in every line though...

I currently have:

```
from re import *
for line in file:
    r = 'chr\d+'
    i = search(r, line)
    if i in line:
```

but I don't know how to make sure it is the same in every line...

**In reference to sajattack's answer**

```
fp = open(infile, 'r')
for line in fp:
        filestring = ''
        filestring +=line
        chrlist = search('chr\d+', filestring)
        chrlist = chrlist.group()
        for chr in chrlist:
            if chr != chrlist[0]:
                print('Every gene in file not on same chromosome')
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input text (more than one line) and what is considered "valid"? If the line has `chr11` then every other line in the file should also contain `chr11` in the string?

Comment: This sounds like a _very_ straighforward application of Python's [string functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and [regex library](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Perhaps a bit too straightforward to be worth posting a question on SO...

Comment: Right, it is very straightforward. I just keep running into errors, I am new to programming and in need of some help.

Comment: What have you tried? If you are having trouble getting a bit of code to work, you should show the code you are having trouble with, and describe what isn't working or isn't as you expect.

Comment: I added what I have above, but am unsure where to go with it... Sorry for the noob question. I just really need some assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the file and have a while loop check each line to make sure it contains `chr11`.  There are string functions to search for substrings in a string.  As soon as you find a line that returns false (does not contain `chr11`) then break out of the loop and set a flag `valid = false`.

```
import re

fp = open(infile, 'r')
fp.readline()
tar = re.findall(r'chr\d+', fp.readline())[0]
for line in fp:
    if (line.find(tar) == -1):
        print("Not valid")
        break
```

This should search for a number in the line and check for validity.

Comment: Right, but I need to make the number variable, in case it was not chr11 I was looking for, yet a different chr. They just all need to be the same chr(then number(s))

Comment: Here's the thing. With the file I am given. I am not wanting to input a number to see if that chromosome is in there. I just want to make sure no matter what number is on the chr in one line, that it is that same one on every other line in the file. But I cannot have an input of a number in the function...

Comment: So you have 10 lines.  All 10 lines have `chr11` and that is valid? Now if line 5 has `chr12` that is invalid? And you just want to feed it the file path as the only argument.

Comment: Correct. I am pretty sure I want to start my function with: for line in file:

Comment: The updated function uses the first line as reference.  So if the first line has `chr15` then that is the number that every subsequent line is compared against.  If any line doesn't have `chr15` then it immediately breaks out of the loop and returns false.

Comment: Are you doing line[line.find("chr"):line.find("chr")+5] because chr has two numbers following it? What it chr had only one number following it, or three numbers? Also, sorry to nipick, but the way I have my function already set up, I have defined a function far above and just need to include this conditional in the middle. That is why I believe it must start with for fp = open(file, 'r') then for line in fp: then the conditional

Comment: Well if you want variable length chr then use `re.findall(r'chr\d+', line)[0]` instead.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, this may be even easier that I thought originally if this is used. I was just having trouble following the numbers with the zero at the end of that and the ==-1 (still not sure what this means)

Comment: Also the first line is different from all the others, it is the column titles, does this matter?

Comment: The first line looks like 

#name chrom strand txStart txEnd cdsStart cdsEnd exonCount exonStarts exonEnds

Comment: If the first line is column titles, just add a `fp.readline()` before the `tar = re.findall(r'chr\d+', fp.readline())[0]` that will make it read the first line and have `tar = re.findall(r'chr\d+', fp.readline())[0]` start at the second line.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume that the first chr is the correct one? If so, use this:

```
import re
chrlist = re.findall("chr[0-9]+",  open('file').read())
# ^ this is a list with all chr(whatever numbers)
for chr in chrlist:
    if chr != chrlist[0]
        print("Chr does not match")
        break
```

Comment: Well, this may work becuase it may not matter whether the first or 22nd one is right, as long as all the others are equal to that one, it should be ok, right?

Comment: This actually may not work, because this is saying for each element of the list (of any possible numbers, which is a hard list to make), if that element is not equal to the list it doesn't match, correct?

Comment: It's making a list of all the chr(whatever numbers) in the string that we are checking. So let's say we're checking "NM_001003443 chr11 + 5997152 5927598 5921052 5926098 1 5928752,5925972, 5927204,5396098, NM_001003444 chr11 + 5925152 5926098 5925152 5926098 2 5925152,5925652, 5925404,5926098, NM_001003489 chr10 + 5925146 5926095 5925152 5926045 4 5925151,5925762, 5987404,5908098, chr11 + 5925145 5926093 5925115 5926045 4 5925151,5925762, 5987404,5908098, the list would be ['chr11', 'chr11', 'chr10', 'chr11']

Comment: Oh! Ok, then I believe this does work! I misinterpreted it, thinking that you were trying to make a list of every possible number. Thanks for explaining that to me

Comment: So if I were to put, 'for line in file:' above the 'chrlist =' and change 'a string in your file' to 'line', this should be functional?

Comment: No, you want the string to be the entire file.

Comment: Well, if I am going through the file line by line, isn't this doing the same thing? Also, why did you add re.group before the search? I though re.group could only be followed by a number, such as re.group(2)

Comment: Sorry, I did the group thing wrong at first. I fixed it now. It isn't doing the same thing if you go line by line. If you go line by line, the list will only contain that line.

Comment: So I have to complicate it a bit and strip the lines of the file and add it to an empty string, then use said empty string to do this?

Comment: Ok, I am going to edit my code above to this, could you tell me if it is correct?

Comment: You need to do chrlist = chrlist.group() after chrlist = search('chr\d+', filestring). search just returns a match object. Also, it should be filestring +=line+"\n" just to keep things neater.

Comment: Good catch there, I added it above

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses a "match group" to collect the matched numbers from the "chr" string.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\schr(\d+)\s')

def chr_val(line):
    m = re.search(pat, line)
    if m is not None:
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return ''

def is_valid(f):
    line = f.readline()
    v = chr_val(line)
    if not v:
        return False

    return all(chr_val(line) == v for line in f)

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    print("The file is {0}".format("valid" if is_valid(f) else "NOT valid"))
```

Notes:

- Pre-compiles the regular expression for speed.
- Uses a raw string (`r''`) to specify the regular expression.
- The pattern requires white space (`\s`) on either side of the `chr` string.
- `is_valid()` returns `False` if the first line doesn't have a good `chr` value.  Then it returns a Boolean value that is true if all of the following lines match the `chr` value of the first line.
- Your sample code just prints something like `The file is True` so I made it a bit friendlier.

Comment: This appears to work from looking at it. Yet since I am only trying to make this a small part of a larger function, I am not trying to make multiple functions. I am unsure how to incorporate this inside a function without calling other functions, this may be a little to complicated for what I am looking for, although I am sure it works. It just may not be usable as is inside another function.

Comment: I really am not sure what you are asking me here.  Why would this code be difficult to call from another function?

Comment: Well, you can't define a function within a function, right? I know you can call one, but I don't know what to input into those functions called inside the base function

Comment: First of all, in Python, you can define a function within a function.  Second of all, you can just put these function definitions in your source code above your function, and they will be defined and made available to your function.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could define a function within a function, that's pretty cool. Thanks!

Comment: You can do it, but you don't need to do it here.  Look at my example: I just define one function at the top, and the below it I have another function that can use the first one.