# Python, Read a text file and print out a list of invalid user names

Tags: python

I need to read the linux /var/log/auth.log file and print the user of unsuccessful logins to the system. Some lines of the file will look like this:

```
May 26 07:29:20 instance-1 sshd[20327]: Disconnected from 61.147.247.146 port 45177 [preauth]
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Invalid user nagios from 159.65.144.233 port 49715
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: input_userauth_request: invalid user nagios [preauth]
May 26 07:32:23 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Received disconnect from 159.65.144.233 port 49715:11: Normal 
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Invalid user admin from 159.65.144.233 port 49715
```

I need to read the lines of data from this file, and print out a sorted list to a file of invalid user names, one per line, like the list shown below.

```
nagios 
admin
```

I have made progress. I stripped everything before and after the username, however I need it to be sorted.

```
    errors = []                   # The list where we will store results.
    linenum = 0
    substr = "Invalid user"          # Substring to search for.
    with open ('auth.log', 'rt') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if line.find(substr) != -1:
            errors.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
    fake_users = []
    for line in users:
        fake_users = (line.split("Invalid user")[1])
        print(fake_users.partition("from")[0])
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a regex to grab the username after each Invalid user line. Regex might be a little overkill, but it seems appropriate to me here. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import re
input_ = '''
May 26 07:29:20 instance-1 sshd[20327]: Disconnected from 61.147.247.146 
port 45177 [preauth]
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Invalid user nagios from 
159.65.144.233 port 49715
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: input_userauth_request: invalid 
user nagios [preauth]
May 26 07:32:23 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Received disconnect from 
159.65.144.233 port 49715:11: Normal 
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Invalid user admin from 
159.65.144.233 port 49715
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'Invalid user (\b\w+\b)')
for line in input_.split('\n'):
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match is not None:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Here's a somewhat similar question I found: [match an element of every line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308340/match-an-element-of-every-line)

And if you're not familiar with regular expressions in Python, check out the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to NBartley's answer, it seems to me that your main ask is how to sort your username array. See below.

```
import re
input_ = '''
May 26 07:29:20 instance-1 sshd[20327]: Disconnected from 61.147.247.146 
port 45177 [preauth]
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Invalid user nagios from 
159.65.144.233 port 49715
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: input_userauth_request: invalid 
user nagios [preauth]
May 26 07:32:23 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Received disconnect from 
159.65.144.233 port 49715:11: Normal 
May 26 07:32:22 instance-1 sshd[20351]: Invalid user admin from 
159.65.144.233 port 49715
'''
output = []
pattern = re.compile(r'Invalid user (\b\w+\b)')
for line in input_.split('\n'):
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match is not None:
        output+= [match.group(1)]
output = output.sort()
print(output)
```

Comment: Other than sort, I modified NBartley's and it works well. However the output.sort does not work in yours. It returns None many times. Thank you all for the help.